# Read in first 5 lines, print specified line

Tags: perl

I am trying to read in the first 5 lines of my input file and print only a single line (in this case line 4) that is given to the perl script from the command line.  I am having some trouble comparing the current line number to the specified line number.

Here is the important part of my perl script:

```
# Variables
my $sInputFile = $ARGV[0];
my $sOutputFile = $ARGV[1];
my $sRowExtractNumber = $ARGV[2];

# Open-Close / Exceptions
open(my $in, "<", $sInputFile) or die "cannot open output file: $sOutputFile\n";
open(my $out, ">", $sOutputFile) or die "cannot open input file: $sInputFile\n";

# Script
while (<$in>) {
    if (1..5) {
        print $out $_ if $_ == $sRowExtractNumber;
    }
}
```

I am not getting an error per say, but nothing is being printed to the `$out` file.

How can I accomplish my goal?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$.` variable is the current input line number. I presume you used `$_` by mistake.

There is no need to check both that the line number is five or less *and* that it matches the requested line, although you may want to verify your input beforehand.

You must *always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of every module. It is a simple measure that will alert you to many trivial mistakes that you could otherwise easily overlook. And you should use lower case letters for local identifiers: upper case is reserved for globals such as package names.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($input_file, $output_file, $row_extract_number) = @ARGV;

die "Line number must be five or less" if $row_extract_number < 1 or $row_extract_number > 5;

open my $in,  '<', $input_file   or die qq{Cannot open "$input_file" for input: $!}
open my $out, '>', $output_file  or die qq{Cannot open "$output_file" for output: $!}

while (<$in>) {
  if ($. == $row_extract_number) {
    print $out $_;
    last;
  }
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the tips on top of the answer. Will keep those in mind.